# Gradle plugin dependency (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write gradle plugin, which is dependent on RPM nebula plugin (it basically wraps it). I compile the plugin without any issues. In generated ivy.xml I have

```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency org="com.netflix.nebula" name="gradle-ospackage-plugin" rev="4.1.0" conf="compile-&gt;default"/>
  </dependencies>
```

Which feels ok, but when I apply my plugin in application, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/gradle/plugins/rpm/RpmPlugin
    at com.cisco.td.gradle.rpm.ServiceRpmPlugin$_configureProject_closure2.doCall(ServiceRpmPlugin.groovy:27)
    at com.cisco.td.gradle.rpm.ServiceRpmPlugin.configureProject(ServiceRpmPlugin.groovy:26)
```

When executing this section of code

```
    project.plugins.with {
        apply RpmPlugin
    }
```

---

I have tried to add the dependency on build classpath from my plugin class using

```
    project.buildscript.dependencies {
        classpath "com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:4.1.0"
    }
```

But this throws:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':classpath' after it has been resolved.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.validateMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:631)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$2.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.assertMutable(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:274)
```

---

It works, when I add the nebula dependency directly to the application project as a buildscript dependency, but this is not how I think it should work - the plugin should download all its dependencies and the client should not care...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours - the problem was, that pom.xml was not generated. When created using

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
      mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
      }
  }
}
```

it works as expected...